# SQL Server : restore from backup but keep ID (identity) references

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, recovery

I have the following scenario. Let's say I have 3 tables:

IDs are integers and primary key with identity(1,1).

- `Clients` (ID (pk), Name)
- `Orders` (ID (pk), ClientID (fk), Date)
- `OrderDetails` (ID (pk), OrderID (fk), Product, Quantity, Price)

Let's say I accidentally deleted all records from those 3 tables, but I have a DB backup. The question is how do I reinsert those deleted records from backed up DB into the current DB?

I know I can simply `"set identity_insert on"` and use `"insert into"`, but is a web application and it must stay alive and there are inserts from users going on.

If I insert all `Clients` back, their ID will be different and `Orders(ClientID)` cannot refers to that anymore. So on with `Orders/OrderDetails` tables.

I need some way to update the foreign key ids with new ones. How can I do that?

Some kind of temp tables to keep records of old IDs and new IDs?

Hope that I made my question clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd:

1. Determine which rows are in your backup that aren't in your live database
2. Insert the rows from your backup into your live database with a value of -1 * identity value. For instance, if the row was in the backup with a identity value of 1234, you'd insert it into your live database with an identity value of -1234. This goes not only for identity values, but for any rows that reference those values (i.e. foreign keys).